# jQuery library 1.4.4 not allowing spaces in textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using asp text boxes and some javascript code in my project.

After seeing that spaces in my text boxes are disabled, I went through similar problems others have been faced with and got that mostly javascript makes this kind of issues. So after trying I got that jQuery library 1.4.4 is the cause. But by removing that, my slideshow would be disabled.

Any idea what could be the better or a proper solution for this?

[Here](http://bijanarts.somee.com/) is the sample.

The result of what I've tried shows me that the scripts below in file " jq1.js " is making the issue.

```
$(function () {
  $('#MainGalleryData .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData2 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData3 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData4 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData5 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData6 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData7 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData8 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData9 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData10 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData11 .test').lightBox();
  $('#MainGalleryData12 .test').lightBox();
```

});

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('#MainSlidesUl').fadeSlideShow();
});
```

Comment: I did and used 1.8 but slideshow remains disabled anyway.

Comment: don't thin there are any extrasensory here. Provide us some JsFiddle or code where you face a problem

Comment: I just put the sample in the question.

Comment: I don't recall 1.4.4. having an issue with spaces in text boxes. Are you sure this isn't some deliberately coded inhibition?

Comment: neither I do. and yes I am sure. But what is it to do with 1.4.4 library?

Comment: Are you using Gallerific for the slideshow? If so, a fix is published here on SO. I found it with a Google search. Alternatively, run Galleriffic with the option `enableKeyboardNavigation: false`.

Comment: I don't think it could be a problem of Jquery. Why don't you try to add all the js in one new page and your form as well and try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Beetroot, No it not. It's an old plugin written by "John Resig" using library 1.2.3 .

Comment: @Nil, I've tried that too and Just now I got that which script is making the problem. I'll put that in the code.

Comment: OK it's not Galleriffic but it's the same issue. Slideshow keyboard navigation steals the spacebar. See js/jq1.js, lines 283-286.

Comment: Good point. Simon also noticed the same. You guys are good at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in `<script src="js/jq1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
Search for `32`, this is keycode for `space`. You will find following code:

```
    if (settings.allowKeyboardCtrl) {
        jQuery(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 39) {
                var nextSlide = ActSlide - 1;
                stopAutoplay();
                jumpTo(nextSlide);
            } else if (e.which == 37) {
                var prevSlide = ActSlide + 1;
                stopAutoplay();
                jumpTo(prevSlide);
            } else if (e.which == 32) {
                if (intval) { stopAutoplay(); }
                else { autoplay(); }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

So when pressing space it will return false, which is the reason for your "error". You should either disable it or check event if it is an input, e.g.:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
    if ($(event.target).is('input') == false) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect. but Why is this condition used for a slideshow ? and by the way I changed that to some other number and the problem solved. Isn't changing that going to make another problem ?

Comment: I can't tell you why slideshows author did it that way. I event don't think that it's necessary to control slideshow by keypresses. To what other number did you change it? If you change it e.g. 65, you won't be able to type an `a`. Have a look at javascript key codes: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: I changed that to 332 for a try which would make the condition useless right?

Comment: Suggest you comment out `} else if (e.which == 32) {` and the following three lines. This will kill spacebar's toggle action for autoplay, and fix the issue.

Comment: Yea I finally commented/disabled that. And one final question! Totally how do you evaluate the javascript codes and implementation of libraries in my project ?

Comment: If you must have a keyboard shortcut for autoplay toggle, then change `} else if (e.which == 32) {` to `} else if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 32) {` instead of commenting out. This has the effect of requiring the control key to be down for spacebar to acquire the togggle action.

Comment: @John Do you want to control autoplay? Then use my answer. You don't? Then use Beetroots answer!

Comment: @ Beetroot-Beetroot, Although not needed,I thank you for trying and showing me that.

Comment: That slideshow plugin is so old, I would find a more recent alternative. Reading the code, I find it hard to believe it's written by Resig. He must have learned a whole lot since those days. There's some bad stuff in there, which would make him blush today.

Comment: @John You can try out nivo slider, it's pretty good plugin and easy to handle: http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/

Comment: @Simon,I've applied nivo sliders before but this time I just needed something with easy navigation and control and also lightweight. But what are the MAIN reasons that u are suggesting nivo slider?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, I understand that plugin is too old and may have problems in some cases but as I said above the navigation and controls were needed for me and therefor I chose this one.